# Is it possible to create docker image from .img file containing OS

Tags: docker, docker-image

Is it possible to convert an `.img` file containing an OS (Arch Linux) into a Docker image? More precisely I want to *dockerize* a RuneAudio Raspberry Pi image.

Comment: have a look at `docker load` and `docker save` https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/   and   https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/

Comment: it seems, docker load is expecting only tar file created with docker save. Unfortunately it does not work with my .img file
`$ docker load -i RuneAudio_rpi2_0.3-beta_20150304_2GB.img`
_Error response from daemon: Untar re-exec error: exit status 1: output: archive/tar: invalid tar header_

Comment: you get the idea, do a tar of your OS and try

Comment: Take a look at how the base OS images at Docker hub are built from the tar files. Example: https://github.com/CentOS/sig-cloud-instance-images/blob/f0b1738ab545dccaae07a57eab0fc7356a96d404/docker/Dockerfile

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Producing a Docker image from a full operating system image is often a sub-optimal process.  The operating system image is going to include a variety of things that are simply not necessary in the Docker environment, which simply means that the resulting image is going to be unnecessarily large.

That said, if you want to try this anyway, the `guestfish` command from the [libguestfs](http://libguestfs.org/) package makes this very simple:

```
guestfish --ro -a RuneAudio_rpi_0.3-beta_20141029_2GB.img -m /dev/sda5:/ tar-out / - |
docker import - runeaudio
```

That will create a `runeaudio`  docker image with the contents of the `RuneAudio_rpi_0.3-beta_20141029_2GB.img` disk image.  Note that this will, of course, only run under Docker running on a Raspberry Pi, and the resulting image isn't necessarily going to work without further modification.

You can also accomplish the same thing by mounting the disk image locally:

```
losetup -P /dev/loop0 RuneAudio_rpi_0.3-beta_20141029_2GB.img
mount /dev/loop0p5 /mnt
tar -C /mnt -cf - | docker import - runeaudio
umount /mnt
losetup -d /dev/loop0
```

I like `guestfish` because it doesn't require root access, and doesn't require mucking about with loop devices and mountpoints, so there's less setup and cleanup.